# Sending scheduled email using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I am developing Email Campaign module in which user can create EmailCampaign with some criteria selection and can send emails to thousands of users.

At now I have found 2 ways of implementation as below, but need to know which approach will be better to use:

1)First windows service keeps checking database at n mins of interval and  inserts data in email queue table for eligible Email Campaigns &Second service keeps taking around 1000s of records from queue and sends them.

2)In web application, on application start take all email campaigns created and schedule them using quartz(or any other background job helper) to execute(generate queue as well as send out email) on defined time. In this approach I believe it may create internal threads , will it affect working of web application?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 0):

Approach #1: Separate from the system. No load on application itself. But do clear your database regularly. Use UniqueIdentifier IDs for email tables and not identity so that clearing data would not cause loss of intermittent numbers. You should only keep email template in database. Bind it to data at runtime and send the mail. It depends on requirements but do you need to keep the sent mail for everyone in the active database all the time.

Approach #2: It will in any case have an effect on memory consumption on the web application, and may slow down your application. Are there multiple servers or one? If there are multiple, will they work on same data and send multiple mails for same stuff. How will the instances sync amongst themselves. You may need to partition data between instances. Or will they also use SQL database at runtime to get the data for processing. If there is only server, this will run without issue anyways.

If you have data available in the database, you can also plan to use SQL database for same if there is no formatting required in email. A SQL job will handle it much better.

Also, you can do this thing through a powershell script / windows exe running through windows task scheduler at multiple times which connects to DB and sends mail.

You can also use Hangfire for background processing stuff in .net. Keep background memory consumption low and use appropriate error handling.

https://www.hangfire.io/

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's some operations/business stuff that will make #1 painful, I'd go with #1 because of the following...

- If business folks wanted the email format to change (e.g. put the logo on the left instead of the right, make the unsubscribe text blue instead of green...), the guys creating the campaign will not experience any downtime.
- Campaign creating folks wouldn't be slowed down if they create a campaign that targets a large number of users.
- If you want to tweak options on sending emails (e.g. play with load distribution, use different servers for different stuff, etc ), you wouldn't have to interrupt your application users by deploying a new version of your webapp that has the new tweak

YMMV